# Finding the 3 smallest numbers in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
| songtitle  | songlength  | 
|------------|-------------|
| 1          |      3:42   |
| 2          |      1:32   |
| 3          |      2:44   |
| 4          |      5:00   |
| 5          |      1:19   |
| 6          |      2:54   |
```

And I want to get the 3 shortest songs (sorted shortest to longest).

I figure I will need something like `LIMIT` but I'm not positive. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the data and limit the number of rows you want to retreive:

```
select *
from your_table
order by songlength
limit 3;
```

If you'd like to get the 3 *longest* songs, simply order the data in descending order:

```
select *
from your_table
order by songlength desc
limit 3;
```

---

Addressing Dwza's comment, quoting from [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. [...] To sort in reverse order, add the `DESC` (descending) keyword to the name of the column in the `ORDER BY` clause that you are sorting by. **The default is ascending order**; this can be specified explicitly using the `ASC` keyword.

Comment: 1 up from here but my question is... don't you have to pass ASC to the first query ?

Comment: ah ok, didn't knew that... and I only can up a answere once :) Thx for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "SORT" function to sort them natively in MySQL.

Comment: My question : How did know that he using php? and why convert it to minutes when can ordered by sql as simple as answer above?